# Installing mmenu in concrete5

Tags: jquery, concrete5

I am trying to get mmenu: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl to work with our concrete5 template and I am having difficulties. I'm not extremely familiar with concrete5, but it's what our company chose to use. Where do I need to link the .js and .css files from? Does anybody have any experience with this.

Comment: There should be an assets folder with css and js subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of great tutorials on building themes for concrete5. Basically you want to put the files in `/themes/yourTheme/mmenu/` then in your header.php (usually in `/themes/yourTheme/elements/`) include the lines you need. jQuery is already included in the `<?php Loader::element('header_required') ?>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/mmenu/jquery.mmenu.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getThemePath(); ?>/mmenu/jquery.mmenu.js" />
```